# Attempting to graph changes per second in counter

Tags: prometheus

The query:

```
increase(Application_hystrix_command_count_success[10s])
```

This seems to be the query I need, from my understanding of the function, however the data it returns does not seems to be correct, sometimes.

The data for the counter looks something like:

```
    101 @1507897406.565
    101 @1507897407.565
    101 @1507897408.565
    101 @1507897409.565
    101 @1507897410.565
    101 @1507897411.565
    101 @1507897412.565
    101 @1507897413.565
    102 @1507897414.565
    102 @1507897415.565
```

What I am seeing in the graph is some of the spikes are fluctuating. For instance a spike that should be 10 cycles between these values when refreshing the graph:

```
    10
    11.1111111111111
    7.77777777777777
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is not exact, the above samples for example aren't exactly aligned to the second. This means that we need to extrapolate a bit when the data doesn't exactly cover the 10s range, which can cause artifacts like this. On average however, the result will be correct.

[Counting with Prometheus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67Ulrq6DxwA) goes into this in more detail.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, the video really helped!